# WADPerformanceCounters, HR and HRI Tables

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

I'm using Azure and I'm using performance counters. I have seen that performance counters are stored in WADPerformanceCountersTable. I have seen too that some kind of tables related with performance counters are created. The names are WADPTMRTable and WADPTMRITable. What these tables are?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell these tables where the performance counter information for the management portal is pulled from.  This information is summary information based on the raw data that can be found in the WADPerformaceCountersTable.

Comment: Thank you knightpfhor. I'm working around this and I think the same.